# Deploying grails 2.1.1 war to JBoss 5.1

Tags: jboss5.x, grails-2.0

I've recently upgraded our grails app from 1.3.7 to 2.1.1.

I'm attempting to deploy it to JBoss 5.1 but am running into problems.

I get the following error during deployment:

```
Failed to create Resource myapp-2.0.war - cause: java.lang.RuntimeException:org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException: Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS): 
*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error vfszip:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myapp-2.0.war/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: 
URL file:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/4sp3y1b-x797w6-haf9ykfc-1-hafaajh5-ng/myapp-2.0.war/ deployment failed DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: 
Deployment "vfszip:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/myapp-2.0.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: 
URL file:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/4sp3y1b-x797w6-haf9ykfc-1-hafaajh5-ng/app-2.0.war/ deployment failed -> org.jboss.deployers.client.spi.IncompleteDeploymentException:Summary of incomplete deployments (SEE PREVIOUS ERRORS FOR DETAILS): 
*** DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Name -> Error vfszip:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app-2.0.war/ -> org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: 
URL file:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/4sp3y1b-x797w6-haf9ykfc-1-hafaajh5-ng/app-2.0.war/ deployment failed DEPLOYMENTS IN ERROR: Deployment "vfszip:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/app-2.0.war/" is in error due to the following reason(s): 
org.jboss.deployers.spi.DeploymentException: URL file:/C:/Users/e034791/Documents/tools/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/tmp/4sp3y1b-x797w6-haf9ykfc-1-hafaajh5-ng/app-2.0.war/ deployment failed
```

After much googling I've added the following files under web-app/WEB-INF:

***jboss-web.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 5.0//EN" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">

<jboss-web>
    <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
        <loader-repository>
            com.app.deals:loader=app-2.0.war
            <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
        </loader-repository>
    </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

***jboss-classloading.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classloading xmlns="urn:jboss:classloading:1.0"
    export-all="NON_EMPTY" import-all="true" domain="DefaultDomain"
    top-level-classloader="true" parent-first="false">
</classloading>
```

***jboss-scanning.xml***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<scanning xmlns='urn:jboss:scanning:1.0'>
   <path name='WEB-INF/lib/grails-datastore-gorm-*.jar'>
      <include name='org.grails.datastore' />
   </path>
</scanning>
```

I added the scanning file after reading [this](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8606) link.

But still no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downgraded to grails 2.1.0 and everything worked without needing any classloading.xml.

I ran into multiple issues with grails 2.1.1 and JBoss 5. Classloading.xml appeared to have no effect and I continued to get various clasloading issues (Parent last config seemed to be doing nothing).